# Are IPs assinged by APIPA static?

Tags: windows, networking, ip, virtual-machines

I have two virtual machines that are on the same network via VirtualBox. There is no DHCP server and their IPs are assinged by the APIPA automatically. I'm wondering are those IP static, in a way that they down change when I restart those VMs. I have restarted them a couple of times and IPs appear to be the same. I'm also unable to find any explanation on this; what exactly is running APIPA(service, process, .exe file...?), can it be turned off and are there any sheme of assigning IPs or it's just random.

Host machine is Win 7 64-bit and two clients are also Win 7 64-bit. I'm running VirtualBox.

Thanks xD.

Comment: The IPv4 Link-Local addressing (APIPA) is covered in _[RFC 3927, Dynamic Configuration of IPv4 Link-Local Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3927)_.

Comment: They're not static in the sense that static implies being manually assigned, which APIPA addresses are not. Can it be turned off? Yes, it can be disabled via the Registry.

Comment: The odds of something generating the same IPv4 Link-Local address are supposed to be large because a host is required to use a pseudo-random number genrator when assigning itself an address. "_When a host wishes to configure an IPv4 Link-Local address, it selects an address using a pseudo-random number generator with a uniform distribution in the range from 169.254.1.0 to 169.254.254.255 inclusive._"

Comment: I'm asking after IP is generated first and then when you restart PC or remove it and add it to network again.